# How to Remove the Parent Div using PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

```
$html_string = '<div class="quote" post_id="57" 
style="border:1px solid #000;padding:15px;margin:15px;" 
user_id="1" user_name="david_cameron"><strong><span 
style="font-size:200%;">My Name is Rashid Farooq</span></strong></div>';
```

I want to remove the Parent Div and get only the following output

```
<strong><span style="font-size:200%;">My Name is David Cameron</span></strong>
```

I have tried

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$innerHTML_contents = $divs->item(0)->textContent
echo $innerHTML_contents
```

But It gives me the only 'My Name is David Cameron' and strip all the tags.
How Can I remove only the parent div and get all other html contents in the div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use this function

```
function DOMinnerHTML($element) 
{ 
   $innerHTML = ""; 
   $children = $element->childNodes; 
   foreach ($children as $child) 
   { 
      $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
      $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
      $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
   } 
   return $innerHTML; 
}
```

like

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$innerHTML_contents = DOMinnerHTML($divs->item(0));
echo $innerHTML_contents
```

output

```
 <strong><span style="font-size:200%;">My Name is Rashid Farooq</span></strong>
```